# how to measure latency and jitter for Wimax in matlab

Tags: matlab, voip, skype, latency, wimax

I am using USB dongle Wimax  and I am using Skype as VOIP application . I need to measure the latency and jitter when I am using Skype using Matlab. please any help with this.

Comment: I don't know about MatLab, but I do know of a website that measures jitter and latency: [pingtest](http://pingtest.net).

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question. Is there even a MatLab library or something that handles network activity (NOT neural networks, but computer networks) ? That seems to be the better question to ask, IMO...

Comment: Thanks .. I will do  some research about that.

Comment: this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_traffic_measurement) article seems to suggest that using SNMP or packet sniffing is possible. Perhaps there is a way to use that with MatLab?